# Are there any fast algorithm to estimate a Bernoulli mixture model?

Tags: estimation, bernoulli-distribution, mixture-distribution, finite-mixture-model

In a problem I need to estimate a  Bernoulli mixture model with 3 mixing components. More specifically, we have a random vector $\mathbf{D}=(D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4,D_5)$.  $D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4,D_5$ are drawn from independent $Bernoulli(p^1_1),Bernoulli(p^1_2),Bernoulli(p^1_3),Bernoulli(p^1_4),Bernoulli(p^1_5)$ with probability $w_1$, drawn from independent $Bernoulli(p^2_1),Bernoulli(p^2_2),Bernoulli(p^2_3),Bernoulli(p^2_4),Bernoulli(p^2_5)$ with probability $w_2$, and drawn from independent $Bernoulli(p^3_1),Bernoulli(p^3_2),Bernoulli(p^3_3),Bernoulli(p^3_4),Bernoulli(p^3_5)$ with probability $w_3$. That is, in each mixing component, the five Bernoulli variables are independent.  I'm interested in estimating $(p^s_1,p^s_2,p^s_3,p^s_4,p^s_5)_{s=1}^3$ using $n$ repeated i.i.d. draws for $\mathbf{D}$ denoted by $\{\mathbf{D}_1,...,\mathbf{D}_n\}$. It would be great if the estimator could be finished within a few seconds because I need to repeat the estimation thousands of times. Thanks!

Comment: Because your "multivariate Bernoulli" specifications look like they involve only as many parameters as components of the vector, they don't seem to have any information about the dependencies among the components.  But if there are no dependencies, and therefore the components are independent, then why use the "multivariate Bernoulli" description?  Each is just five independent Bernoulli variables.  That sounds far simpler than dealing with a fully multivariate Bernoulli model.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, Whuber! You are right! I will revise the question.

Comment: Now that you have simplified the problem statement, consider a single component.  Could you tell us how a "Bernoulli mixture model" for that component would differ from a Bernoulli distribution?  Because I understand any Bernoulli model to concern a binary random variable, its distribution is completely determined by a single parameter $p$ -- the probability of one of the specific values of that variable.  A mixture of such distributions would just be another Bernoulli distribution.